# Java library for finding executables

Tags: java

I am using the the `ProcessBuilder` class to execute executables on Windows and Linux.

Is there an easy way to find these executables without knowing the directory path to the executable.

e.g.

```
//which command functionality
String executable = which("executable_name");

List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add(executable);
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
..
..
```

It would be great if there was a function like the which command on linux?

Any ideas or will I have to loop over and parse the PATH environment variables using the

```
System.getenv("PATH");
```

Comment: You can can call `process = new ProcessBuilder("which", "executable_name").start();` and read the output (but that will only work on linux).

Comment: You can can call process = new ProcessBuilder("where", "executable_name").start(); and read the output (but that will only work on windows). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `where` command on Windows.

```
WHERE [/R dir] [/Q] [/F] [/T] pattern
```

If you do not specify a search directory using `/R`, it searches the current directory and in the paths specified by the PATH environment variable. Here's a sample code that finds the two locations where `notepad.exe` resides on Windows.

```
String searchCmd;
if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
    searchCmd = "where";
} else { // I'm assuming Linux here
    searchCmd = "which";
}

ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(searchCmd, "notepad.exe");
Process process = procBuilder.start();

ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    filePaths.add(scanner.nextLine());
}
scanner.close();

System.out.println(filePaths);
```

***Output:***

```
[C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe, C:\Windows\notepad.exe]
```

**Note:** I've only tested this on Windows. You may have to modify (probably the command options and the way you parse *which* output) to make it work on Linux.